# Save and load an image from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a form with input type = file. After submitting from information from this form goes to localstorage and add to some block. I can add text, but can't add image, not a file name, but a real image.

So the result should look like div with some text info inside and a real image from the user pc

```js
let outputs = $('.output-text');
  let idMask = "outputs_";
  function showArticle(){
    let isLen = localStorage.length;
    if(isLen > 0){
        for(let i = 0; i < isLen; i++){
            let key = localStorage.key(i);
            if(key.indexOf(idMask) == 0){
                $('<div></div>').addClass('student-card')
                    .attr('data-itemId', key)
                    .html(localStorage.getItem(key))
                    .prependTo(outputs);
            }
        }
    }
}

showArticle();


$(".load-form").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let groupName = $(this).find('#select-group option:selected').text();
    let pupilName = $(this).find('#select-pupil option:selected').text();
    let message = $(this).find('#textarea').val();
    let inputImg = $(this).find('#file-name').text();
    let addArticle = '<div class = "student-card__group">Group: <span class = "group-name_js">'+groupName'+
 '</span></div><div class = "student-carg__img">'+inputImg+'</div>';

    let newId = 0;
    outputs.children().each(function(index, el){
        let oldId = $(el).attr('data-itemId').slice(8);
        if(oldId > newId)
            newId = oldId;
    })
    newId++;

    localStorage.setItem(idMask+newId, addArticle);

    $('<div></div>').addClass('student-card')
        .attr('data-itemId', idMask+newId)
        .html(addArticle).prependTo(outputs);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class = "load-form" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class = "load-form-item choose-group">
        <select id = "select-group">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class = "load-form-item">
       <input type = "file">
    </div>
    <div class = "load-form-item load-form-item__submit">
      <input type = "submit">
    </div>
</form>

<div></div>
```

Comment: In order to provide a meaningful answer for your specific case, we will need to know what type of host you have. Is it .NET, PHP, Ruby, etc. The image will most likely need to be read server side and sent back to the browser for local storage.

Comment: No server, just html

Comment: You are hosting it somewhere, right, or are you just running it locally with a file:// url? You should check your hosting environment to determine what type of server-side support is provided.

Comment: I run it locally and on my local server with php for backend, but it should work in html without backend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was incorrect that server side is required. There is a good tutorial on codepen for exactly this [codepen](https://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/CfilG) found from [this blog](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api)

```
<div id="page-wrapper">

<h1>Image File Reader</h1>
<div>
    Select an image file: 
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
</div>
<div id="fileDisplayArea"></div>
```

CSS

```
    html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  border-top: 5px solid #69c773;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#fileDisplayArea {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {

        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');


        fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            var imageType = /image.*/;

            if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "";

                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = reader.result;

                    fileDisplayArea.appendChild(img);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
            } else {
                fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "File not supported!"
            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own code for uploading files and images in Javascript is a known headache.

The solution most people reach for is wiring Paperclip(https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) on your back end.

So when a user uploads an image/file it will go straight to the backend and you'll need to do an API fetch to save it in local storage.

Comment: unfortunately I can't use plugins, just my own code, but I can't write it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [LocalForage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/). it is a asynchronous data store with a simple, localStorage-like API. It allows developers to store many types of data other then just strings. Using [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) as it first choice of which it's capitabel of storing "Clonable Structured Data" including array's objects and even file and blobs in this case.

IndexedDB is the way to go. When using localStorage you can only save strings, You would need FileReader to serialize the string which increase size and page load time.

Here is an example

```
localforage.setItem('somekey', file).then(function (value) {
  // Do other things once the value has been saved.
  console.log(value);

  // This will be a valid blob URI for an <img> tag.
  var imageURI = window.URL.createObjectURL(value);
}).catch(function(err) {
  // This code runs if there were any errors
  console.log(err);
});
```