# Download a PNG file that was uploaded via an input field

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I uploaded a file via

```
<input> id="pdf" type="file"></input>
```

I can access it's content via

```
var inp = document.querySelector("#pdf");
var text = await inp.files[0].text()
```

When calling my download function I get "Failed - Network error" (Chromium) and in Firefox nothing happens (function returns undefined).

```
download("viainput.png",text);
```

But I struggle to save the same file to the file system, I always get corrupted files. My next step would be to send it to another user via webrtc as encoded text

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:image/png;base64,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);
 
  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
 
  element.click();
 
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
 
// Start file download.
download("hello.png",'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save and load an image from input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201299/save-and-load-an-image-from-input)

Comment: first, I don't see where you base64-encode your input file's contents. That may be why it's corrupted. `encodeURIComponent` is URL-encoding, not base64 (use `btoa` instead)

Comment: second, why bother encoding at all ? just File itself, which is a subclass of Blob, with `URL.createObjectURL`.

Comment: @devzero I have a webRTC application where I want to send an image from one perso to another. If I understand the other question correctly It seems like I need a server for this?

Comment: It should be doable over WebRTC, if you can send arbitrary text or binary data

Comment: (which you can — RTCDataChannel.binaryType can even be set to Blob so you don't need extra conversion from/to an ArrayBuffer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current solution doesn't work because you provide URL-encoded data in a string that should be base64-encoded. But forget about that. `data:` URLs are mostly a thing of the past (or should be).

The efficient way to do this is to *not* encode the image into a string. Instead, directly use the File you get from the input.

```js
var file = inp.files[0] // this is what you use
// as second argument for `download`

function download(filename, blob) {
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  link.href = url
  link.download = filename
  document.body.appendChild(link)
  link.click()
  document.body.removeChild(link)
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url) // if you're done with that file
}
```

You can also send the file (which is a Blob by prototype) directly into a WebRTC data channel, then on the other side, create the object URL from the received Blob.

Comment: caveat : If the image is larger than 16 kiB, WebRTC may not be able to send and reconstruct a single message from it, so you'll have to split it and reassemble it yourself from small pieces. But you can ask another question if you need help with that.

Comment: Ah I tried a path with URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(blob,{type:"image/png"}))) Which led me from one error to another. Thank you for this nice solution !

Comment: Thank you for the hint about the size limitation. My next step would be to send a pdf where this size limitation will be definitely a thing. When time comes I definitly will ask another question

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Using_data_channels#concerns_with_large_messages

Comment: Thank you for the link, I dont use WebRTC directly (for my research I build upon jitsi-meet which has an abstraction ober WebRTC). But the size limitation will be sure a point to be careful. I guess the only way to handle this is to chop the file into multiple messages. Bandwith shouldn't be a problem sime it can handle sound and video streams